# LibGDX - draw curved Label

Tags: java, libgdx, label, curve

I want to draw a curved Label, But don't know how. Is there a way to get a curved Label?

[image: Example]

For example, I have this background. I need to draw the 'ARCADIAN DEER' not straight, but curved. Any suggestions on what way I can think?

Comment: Step one would be "have you tried searching for this yourself already? E.g. through the tibgdx manual, on the web, etc"?

Comment: Hi. Sure. There is no common way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best way, but probably the easiest. Assuming you are using Scene2D - make each letter it's own Label, then make a custom helper Group to position and rotate the labels as you like. You might even be able to use a HorizontalGroup for automatic placement along X.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 
Hmm. That should work, but then I'll have performance drop, as I have for about 50 similar cards in the scrollpane.

Comment: Doing this should not make performance worse, it doesn't matter if the glyphs are all in the label or not, if they are drawn consecutively then it will be the same render call, as long as they are all part of the same texture atlas. What you need to do is implement culling on your scroll pane, so only the cards on the screen are drawn. Have a look at ScrollPane.setCullingArea() for that.

Comment: Thanks, @hamham. Will try